# Writing a random number generator to a text file

Tags: python, random

Im trying to create a random number generator that writes to a text file. The full code will execute perfectly with th exception it only executes 1 number. I need it to be 12. I also know that if i take out  the code that produces the the 12 numbers using ap rint command, but as soon as i insert it back in without the print command and try and send it to a txt file it goes back to only doing 1.

```
#This program writes 1 line of 12 random integers, each in the
#range from 1-100 to a text file.

def main():

    import random

    #Open a file named numbersmake.txt.
    outfile = open('numbersmake.txt', 'w')

    #Produce the numbers
    for count in range(12):
        #Get a random number.
        num = random.randint(1, 100)

    #Write 12 random intergers in the range of 1-100 on one line
    #to the file.
    outfile.write(str(num))

    #Close the file.
    outfile.close()
    print('Data written to numbersmake.txt')

#Call the main function
main()
```

Ive done quite  abit of research but I just cant figure out what I am missing. Help?

Comment: your write statement needs to be inside your for loop.

Comment: please fix the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is place your `write()` statement inside of your `for` loop.

```
for count in range(12):
    #Get a random number.
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    #Write 12 random intergers in the range of 1-100 on one line
    #to the file.
    outfile.write(str(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your write statement needs to be inside your for loop:

   ```
   for count in range(12):
       #Get a random number.
       num = random.randint(1, 100)
       #Write 12 random intergers in the range of 1-100 on one line
       #to the file.
       outfile.write(str(num) + ' ')#adds a space, unless you want the numbers to be all togerther
   ```
2. Your Write statement should be:

   `outfile = open('numbersmake.txt', 'a+')`

   So it will not overwrite the text already written, and it will create a new 'numbersmake.txt' if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It only write one number or a line each time and there an error at line
#Produce the numbers
for count in range(12):
#Get a random number.
num = random.randint(1, 100)

not work i repair this by removw for count
and put randomlist.randint(1, 36), 12)

because me want roulette number make 0 to 36 so 37 number addition all result = 666

The devil game

Not able to put more then one data in then file me wahnt they use the file to predict number after enter a lot of game of casino somebody can help me iT's a good start event there an error inside:

#This program writes 1 line of 0-36 random integers, each in the
#range from 0-36 that make 37 number if addition all toguetter arrive at 666 the Devil Games to a text file.

def main():

```
import random

#Open a file named winning_number.txt.
outfile = open('winning_numbber.txt', 'w')
print('666 Winning Roulette by DjSOPEM (Patrick Émile Mercier 2022')

#Produce the numbers
for count in range(7): #this not work
    #Get a random number.
    num = random.randint(0, 36)

#Write 7 random intergers in the range of 0-36 on one line this not work
#to the file.
outfile.write(str(num))

#Close the file.
outfile.close()
print('Data written to winning_number.txt')
print(num)
```

#Call the main function
main()